# Rejected short paper accepted as poster

Tags: publications, research-process, conference, computer-science, poster

I am a 1st year computer science PhD student. I recently submitted a paper to a large conference LBW that was rejected (with fair comments), I re submitted with changes to a smaller conference short paper track but it’s was also rejected (not as fair comments imo). However, they have accepted it as a poster where I would need to condense the paper from 6 pages to 3. The paper would still be included in the proceedings.

I am a bit conflicted on what to do, this would be my first publication. A few academic staff are telling me it wont be worth it as poster publications are the lowest peer reviewed paper and during COVID it is unlikely the conference will be in person (but not impossible as it is still 6 months away).

I would like to publish but is it worth looking for a different conference instead? I would also need to re submit the smaller paper in a few days.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This really depends on so may specific factors individual to your case that we cannot sensibly advise. Your academic advisor is really your best bet. And if that doesn't satisfy you, engage with your immediate local environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, my advice would be to do it unless it would interfere with more valuable work.

For many students, the value of a poster session is to get some disinterested people to look at your work, ask some questions, and give you some feedback. Some of that feedback might be valuable in extending and improving the work. That, alone, has value. I remember some (face to face) poster sessions that were real posters and the people were doing interesting things. I don't know if I helped them or not, but their needing to try to explain their work to me and answer my questions had some value in solidifying their work, I think.

Not earth shattering insight, probably, but exposure and feedback are good.